# running js (or web based) add-ins automatically when email is opened/read

Tags: javascript, email, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

**MY REQUIREMENT - I'm building an Outlook add-in that will detect if an email is a phishing attack. Hence, I need my add-in to run automatically every time an email is opened/read.**

Is there a way that the new Outlook javascript-based (in other words, web-based) add-in can run automatically when a user clicks on

1. an email to read
2. compose an email

I believe this is possible in VSTO-based. I'm finding that a user has to explicitly click on an add-in to run it. VSTO-based runs only on Windows machines and doesn't work on the web.

If this is not supported now, will this be supported in the near future? If not, what will happen to the current VSTO-based spam filter add-ins? Is there no way for such add-ins to be web-based?

Comment: You mean to open the add-in html page automatically when user is in compose/read mode ?

Comment: Thank you for the nudge @SlavaIvanov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have described is event-based approach which you would use in COM/VSTO Outlook add-ins. Office.js API assumes user invocation of the add-in and doesn't support events at the moment. If this is something new you would like to add to the API you may add your scenarios or up vote existing requests from the fellow developers at [officespdev.uservoice.com](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/131778-add-in-outlook). There is recent addition to the API called pinnable task pane: [Implement a pinnable taskpane in Outlook](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/manifests/pinnable-taskpane) which may keep your add-in open when user moves from message to message, but it is still up to user to invoke the add-in.
The following are QandA for you...

> If this is not supported now, will this be supported in the near future?

May be, may be not, but anyway it will take a lot of time to get those features in the wild.

> If not, what will happen to the current VSTO-based spam filter add-ins?

Nothing happen with VSTO add-ins, they are still best feature reach option for Outlook Desktop on Windows. Web based add-ins are not designed to replace them.

> Is there no way for such add-ins to be web-based?

No, they are platform dependent add-in running in process of Outlook.